# char + int gives unexpected result

Tags: java, type-conversion, string-concatenation

I need to print '**H3110 w0r1d 2.0 true**' as output.
Below is the code written and getting output as '3182 w0r1d 2.0 true'.

```
public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main (String[] args){

        char c1= 'H';
        int num1 = 3110;
        char c2='w';
        byte b=0;
        char c3='r';
        int y=1;
        char c4='d';

        float f = 2.0f;
        boolean bool= true;
        String s = c1+num1 + " " + c2+b+c3+y+c4 + " " + f + " " + bool;
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

Query: If I concatenate `H` and `3110`, it is printing as `3182`. Why so?

Comment: Because `char` is being promoted to `int` before the addition, basically. If you use a string instead (`string c1 = "H";`) it'll be fine.

Comment: In a situation like `char + int`, the `char` gets converted to `int` first (its corresponding Unicode value (for beginners, the index in the ASCII table in this case)) and then it is a regular `int + int` addition.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `+` operator does not use string concatenation unless at least one operand is of type `String`. Ignoring the remainder of the `+` operators, you're basically looking for "what happens if I add `char` and `int` together" - and the answer is "`char` is promoted to `int`, and normal integer addition is performed". The promoted value of `'H'` is 72 (as that's the UTF-16 numeric value of 'H'), hence the result of 3182.

The simplest fix for this in your case would be to change the type of `c1` to `String` instead of `char`:

```java
String c1 = "H";
```

That will then use string concatenation instead of integer addition.

Comment: Well, to be accurate, `'H'` is 72 even without the promotion to `int`, since `char` is a *16-bit unsigned integer* according to the Java Language Specification.

Comment: Nice explanation, however using StringBuilder is safer.

Comment: @IQbrod _Safer_ might be the wrong term to explain why `StringBuilder` should be prefered. Performance might be more accurate. However, note that in this particular situation it does not apply since Java already optimizes single-statement concatenation, i.e. `a + b + c + d` (by using a StringBuilder itself in earlier versions and even better mechanisms afterwards).

Answer (score 2):

You should use a [`StringBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) introduced in Java 5 which has methods `.append()` with char/int/long etc...
This class is the correct String concatenator in Java and allow you to concatenate any primitive (char/int/long ...) by its String representation.

```java
System.out.println(4+3+"s"); // will print "7s"
System.out.println(StringBuilder.append(4).append(3).append("s").toString()); // will print "43s"
```

As mentionned by @Zabuzard Java compiler will replace String sum (`+`) by a `StringBuilder` but `char+int` does return an `int` (and `int` isn't a `String`).
*To get a detailed explanation about `char + int` returning `int`.
I suggest you @JonSkeet answer :)*

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        char c1= 'H';
        int num1 = 3110;
        char c2='w';
        byte b=0;
        char c3='r';
        int y=1;
        char c4='d';

        float f = 2.0f;
        boolean bool= true;
        String s = new StringBuilder()
                .append(c1)
                .append(num1)
                .append(c2)
                .append(b)
                .append(c3)
                .append(y)
                .append(c4)
                .append(f)
                .append(bool)
                .toString();
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

Comment: While this answer gives a valuable solution, it would also be nice if it would explain OPs issue and why it fixes the problem.

Comment: @Zabuzard Jon did it perfectly, I won't copy paste his answer

Comment: Fair. Note however that in this particular situation `StringBuilder` does not have any advantages to a plain concatenation `a + b + c + d`. Since the JLS demands that any Java implementation has to optimize such concatenations already. `StringBuilder` only has performance benefits if the concatenation happens over multiple statements (typically in a loop).

Comment: OP expect `+` as a String concatenator but in Java the correct String concatenator is `StringBuilder.append()` which prevents confusion of `char+int` returning an `int`

Comment: That is fair, thats why I would suggest adding a more detailed explanation to highlight this aspect.

Answer (score 0):

An other solution for this problem may be the usage of the static method

```
String.valueOf(c1)
```

A beter way is using the early mentioned StringBuilder but using String.valueOf is another solution with less effect op the code then using StringBuilder.

Comment: Thank you all for the detailed explanation