# int and char concatenation in java

Tags: java

This program receives a word as an input, and if the length of the word is greater than 10, then it should print the first letter of the word, then the number of characters in between the first and last letter, followed by the last letter. Such an input like "introduction" should output i10n. However, when I try concatenating each of them, something goes wrong, so it just outputs 224, which I have no clue why. Why does this happen, and how can I fix this issue? Any help would be appreciated.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = sc.nextInt();

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
      String word = sc.next();

      if (word.length() > 10){
        int lettersInBetween = (word.length() - 2);
        char firstChar = word.charAt(0);
        char lastChar = word.charAt(word.length() - 1);
        System.out.println(firstChar + lettersInBetween + lastChar);
      }
      else {
        System.out.println(word);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [char + int gives unexpected result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65771038/char-int-gives-unexpected-result)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
    System.out.println(firstChar + Integer.toString(lettersInBetween) + lastChar);
```

About the output of the number 224, this explains it very well:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII

"For example, lowercase i would be represented in the ASCII encoding by binary 1101001 = hexadecimal 69 (i is the ninth letter) = decimal 105."

Answer (score 0):

just replace line :

`System.out.println(firstChar + lettersInBetween + lastChar);`

with  below line :

`System.out.println(""+firstChar + lettersInBetween  + lastChar);`

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way of joining multiple String and numeric values in Java. Just remember that, when you have two or more primitive type values e.g. char, short, or int, at the beginning of your string concatenation, you need to explicitly convert the first of them to a String.

`String.valueOf(int i)` method takes an integer value as an argument and returns a string representing the int argument.

`Integer.toString(int i)` method works same as String.valueOf(int i) method. It belongs to the Integer class and converts the specified integer value to String. for e.g. if the passed value is 101 then the returned string value would be “101”.

You can you both of these methods to convert the integer to String.

```
    int lettersInBetween = (word.length() - 2);
    char firstChar = word.charAt(0);
    char lastChar = word.charAt(word.length() - 1);
    String number = String.valueOf(lettersInBetween);
    System.out.println(firstChar + number + lastChar);
```

or

```
    int lettersInBetween = (word.length() - 2);
    char firstChar = word.charAt(0);
    char lastChar = word.charAt(word.length() - 1);
    String number = Integer.toString(lettersInBetween);
    System.out.println(firstChar + number + lastChar);
```